# K fold cross validation not working properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, k-fold

I have created a transfer learning model with RESNET-50. I am using K-fold cross-validation in my model. However, my model is not performing properly. Although I didn't get any error messages, my accuracy values are very weird. They are the same across all the folds. Please find my code below:

```
root_path = 'D:/regionGrowing_MLT/NewSavedRGBImages'
datasetFolderName=root_path
MODEL_FILENAME=root_path+"model_cv.h5"
sourceFiles=[]
classLabels=['Benign', 'Malignant']
X=[]
Y=[]

img_rows, img_cols =  224, 224 # input image dimensions
train_path=datasetFolderName+'/Training/'
validation_path=datasetFolderName+'/validation/'
test_path=datasetFolderName+'/test/'
def transferBetweenFolders(source, dest, splitRate): 
    global sourceFiles
    sourceFiles=os.listdir(source)
    if(len(sourceFiles)!=0):
        transferFileNumbers=int(len(sourceFiles)*splitRate)
        transferIndex=random.sample(range(0, len(sourceFiles)), transferFileNumbers)
        for eachIndex in transferIndex:
            shutil.move(source+str(sourceFiles[eachIndex]), dest+str(sourceFiles[eachIndex]))
    else:
        print("No file moved. Source empty!")
        
def transferAllClassBetweenFolders(source, dest, splitRate):
    for label in classLabels:
        transferBetweenFolders(datasetFolderName+'/'+source+'/'+label+'/', 
                               datasetFolderName+'/'+dest+'/'+label+'/', 
                               splitRate)

def my_metrics(y_true, y_pred):
    accuracy=accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    precision=precision_score(y_true, y_pred,average='weighted')
    f1Score=f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted') 
    print("Accuracy  : {}".format(accuracy))
    print("Precision : {}".format(precision))
    print("f1Score : {}".format(f1Score))
    cm=confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    print(cm)
    return accuracy, precision, f1Score
transferAllClassBetweenFolders('Training', 'test', 0.20)
def prepareNameWithLabels(folderName):
    sourceFiles=os.listdir(datasetFolderName+'/Training/'+folderName)
    for val in sourceFiles:
        X.append(val)
        for i in range(len(classLabels)):
            if(folderName==classLabels[i]):
                Y.append(i)
# Organize file names and class labels in X and Y variables
for i in range(len(classLabels)):
    prepareNameWithLabels(classLabels[i])
X=np.asarray(X)
Y=np.asarray(Y)
batch_size = 32
epoch=100
activationFunction='relu'
def getModel():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))  #### used for regularization (to aviod overfitting)
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    # model.summary()

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=2e-5),
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
model=getModel()
# ===============Stratified K-Fold======================
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
skf.get_n_splits(X, Y)
foldNum=0
for train_index, val_index in skf.split(X, Y):
    #First cut all images from validation to train (if any exists)
    transferAllClassBetweenFolders('validation', 'Training', 1.0)
    foldNum+=1
    print("Results for fold",foldNum)
    X_train, X_val = X[train_index], X[val_index]
    Y_train, Y_val = Y[train_index], Y[val_index]
    # Move validation images of this fold from train folder to the validation folder
    for eachIndex in range(len(X_val)):
        classLabel=''
        for i in range(len(classLabels)):
            if(Y_val[eachIndex]==i):
                classLabel=classLabels[i]
        #Then, copy the validation images to the validation folder
        shutil.move(datasetFolderName+'/Training/'+classLabel+'/'+X_val[eachIndex], 
                    datasetFolderName+'/validation/'+classLabel+'/'+X_val[eachIndex])
        
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                      rescale=1./255,
                      horizontal_flip=True,
                      rotation_range=40,
                      shear_range=0.2,
                      width_shift_range=0.2,
                      height_shift_range=0.2,
                      zoom_range=0.20,
                      fill_mode="nearest")
    validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
        
    #Start ImageClassification Model
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='training')

    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_path,
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,  # only data, no labels
        shuffle=False)   
   
    # fit model
    history=model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                        epochs=epoch)
    
    predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, verbose=1)
    yPredictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    true_classes = validation_generator.classes
    # evaluate validation performance
    print("***Performance on Validation data***")    
    valAcc, valPrec, valFScore = my_metrics(true_classes, yPredictions)
```

My results are below:

```
Epoch 1/100
72/72 [==============================] - 25s 350ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5013
Epoch 2/100
72/72 [==============================] - 25s 349ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5013
Epoch 3/100
72/72 [==============================] - 25s 348ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5013
Epoch 4/100
72/72 [==============================] - 25s 348ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5013
Epoch 5/100
72/72 [==============================] - 25s 352ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5013
Epoch 6/100
72/72 [==============================] - 25s 351ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5013
Epoch 7/100
72/72 [==============================] - 25s 353ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5013
```

As can be seen above, the accuracy values are the same for all epochs which shouldn't be the case. I am not sure exactly where I am making the error. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your model isn't learning. You'll need to adjust hyperparameters. It could be anything really.

Comment: Do you need a learning rate so low? Low learning rates can sometimes get stuck on local minima/maxima.

Comment: If you use softmax output with two neurons, you need to use categorical crossentropy, not the binary one.